# Changing text with jquery, can't get the transitions right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a text effect but the transition is not completely to my liking.

I am replacing a single word in a line of centered text, I make the old word fade out and the new one fade in, but the surrounding text "jumps". I have been trying for a while to figure out how to make it slide to it's new spot somehow by using an animation on margins or width, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Here is a JSfiddle of what I have right now http://jsfiddle.net/DEk7m/3/

What I am trying to achieve is something similar to what is seen in the big title here: https://gumroad.com/

And here is the code:

HTML:

```
<h1 id="changingtext">This is <span>changing</span> text</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
text-align: center;
font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
  var t1 = new Array("changing", "dynamic", "cool");
  var i = 0;
  var tid = setInterval(
      function() {
        $("#changingtext span").animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000, function () {
            $(this).text(t1[i]);
        }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);

        if(i < t1.length -1) 
            i++;
        else i = 0;

      }, 3000 );

});
```

many thanks!

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to fix the width of the `<span>`. Anything beyond that is going to be pretty hard, because the browser doesn't give you much control over how the inline layout mechanism works.

Comment: ... and you could animate the width of the span too; that'd probably help.

Comment: I added a link to something similar that I am trying to achieve, see the big title here: https://gumroad.com/

Answer (score 5):

Width is missing in your demo, Have a look at this,

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1><span id="chkWidth" style="display: none;"></span></h1>
    <h1 id="changingtext">This is <span>changing</span> text</h1>
</body>
```

**Script**

```
$(function() {
  var t1 = new Array("changing", "dynamic", "cool");
  var i = 0;
  var width;
  var tid = setInterval(
      function() {
          $("#changingtext span").animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000, function () {
            $(this).text(t1[i]);
            width = $('#chkWidth').text(t1[i]).width();
            $(this).animate({'opacity': 1, 'width': width}, 1000);
        });

        if(i < t1.length -1) 
            i++;
        else i = 0;

      }, 3000 );

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DEk7m/8/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

[SEE ANOTHER ANSWER COVERING THE SAME QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695877/animate-width-for-only-a-word-in-a-title-in-jquery-css)

BON! No need for `setInterval` when you deal with `.animate()`
An even better approach without the first change gap/jump 
and with dynamically calculated `span` widths:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ururif/7/edit)**</kbd>

CSS:

```
h1 span{
    /* To prevent a jumpy misaligned SPAN due to widths change. */
    vertical-align:top; 
}
```

jQ:

```
$(function() {

  var t=["changing", "dynamic", "cool"],
      $h1 = $("#changingtext"),
      $sp = $h1.find("span"),
      i=0,
      widths=[];

  $.each(t, function(i, v){
      var el = $('<span />', {text:v}).appendTo($h1);
      widths.push(el.width());
      el.remove();
  });

  $sp.css({opacity:0});

  (function loop(){
     i = ++i%t.length;    
     $sp.text(t[i]).animate({width:widths[i]}, 1000, function(){
       $(this).animate({opacity:1},1000).delay(3000).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, loop); 
      });     
  })(); 

});
```

---

This code group

```
  $.each(t, function(i, v){
      var el = $('<span />', {text:v}).appendTo($h1);
      widths.push(el.width());
      el.remove();
  });
```

stores inside our `widths[]` array all the needed widths we need.
We'll treat the `widths[]` iterations same as you already do for `t[]`

than we create a `recursive self-invoking function` (no need for `setInterval` !) where we'll test for `i` to become `0` using a simple `Modulo Operator (Reminder) %`

```
i = ++i%t.length;
```

The function "looping" is simply achieved recalling that function inside the last chained animation callback.

Comment: nice, but while expanding its a little buggy.

Comment: @ShlomiHassid haha ok thanks, just moved the `width animation` inside the first animation callback :) Do you like it now?

Comment: sorry for the poor english

Comment: @ShlomiHassid I got it, edited and added the demo, take a look!

Answer (score 1):

### Animate opacity *and* width

You can set up an object array to include the ideal width for each instance that comes next.

```
var t1 = [ ['changing', '130px'], ['dynamic', '80px'], ['cool','150px'] ],
    i = 0;

var tid = setInterval( function() {

  $("#changingtext span")
  .animate({
    'opacity': 0,
    'width': t1[i][1] },
    500,
    function() {
      $(this).text( t1[i][0] );
    })
  .animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);

  if(i < t1.length -1) 
    i++;
  else
    i = 0;

}, 3000 );
```

**[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEk7m/6/)**.

This is a bit of a static and cumbersome way but it should set you off on the right direction.

You could probably figure out the sizes of the spans dynamically by printing the words as a `span` list, measuring their width and adding their widths to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a working example i quickly made for you: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NuaP9/3/)

As you can see I am using another element that is hidden and contains the next string for calculating the correct width - all u need now is just

```
 Fading out >>> Animating the width >>> Text >>> Fade in.
```

The text is not jumping while fading out because the outer words are floated to the left/right.

Have fun....

## Jquery:

```
var words1 = new Array(  "dynamic", "changing", "cool");
var i1 = 0;
$("#next1").text($("#outer1").text()).hide();
$("#outer1").width($("#next1").width());

 var tid1 = setInterval(
 function() { 
     var word_in1;
     if (typeof  words1[i1+1] !='undefined') { word_in1 = words1[i1+1] } else { word_in1 =
    words1[0]; }
    var by_char_next1 = $("#next1").text('This is '+ word_in1 + ' text').width();
     $("#changingtext1").fadeOut(1000, function(){
         $("#outer1").animate({'width': by_char_next1 },1000,function(){
         $("#changingtext1").text(words1[i1]).fadeIn(1000);
         });
     });
    if (i1 < words1.length-1) i1++;
    else i1 = 0;
   }, 3000 );
```

## CSS:

```
  #outer1,
  #changingtext1
 {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
#next1{
padding:0;
margin:0;
  font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;  
}
```

## HTML:

```
<center>
<div id='outer1' align='center'>
    <span style='float:left;'>This is</span>
    <span id="changingtext1">changing</span>
    <span style='float:right;'>text</span>
</div>
<br />
<span id='next1'></span>
</center>
```