# Animate text, cycle through array of words and colors

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

The accepted answer on [How to fade, animate and change text, word in title / sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695877/how-to-fade-animate-and-change-text-word-in-title-sentence/20696329#20696329?newreg=ecb5a7be917f4b21b31924ababb52c16) does a great job at replacing and animating words in a sentence.

How can I also change the color of those word(s), based on a predefined array of colors?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: I did find some code for the colors, but couldn't integrate it in the existing code because of my limited js skills...

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve it using CSS instead of Javascript with nth-child selector in this way:

```
[data-words] > span:nth-child(2){
  color: blue;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/sel_nth-child.asp