# How do I let only the block code move and other span tag remain unaffected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the text as per the code. Here other span tags are also getting affected by changing of this text. How do I make the other span tags be unaffected?

```js
var para_values = [
  {
    content: "BRAND "
  },
  {
    content: "MISSION"
  }
];

function showVal(index) {
  var val = document.getElementsByClassName("header-para")[0];
  console.log(val);
  val.innerHTML = para_values[index].content;
}

showVal(0); // called for visibility on the screen

// function for changing the content
function textChange() {
  var index = 0;
  var intrvl = setInterval(() => {
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == para_values.length) {
      index = 0;
    }
    showVal(index)
  }, 4000)
}

textChange();
```

```css
.header-para {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 235, 198);
}

.text-overlay span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-overlay">
  <span>Your</span> <span class="header-para"></span><span>Understand</span>
</div>
```

Comment: For the other spans moving when the text changes, you can always give the header-para span a width to match the widest word. So that way the span won't get wider/smaller. And set all spans to be ``display:inline-block;``

Comment: You mean something like [Animate changing words width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20696329/383904) ?

Comment: Please be a little more specific about having the other spans being unaffected. Based on the example, I assume you mean their position?

Comment: Aside: What are "your brand understand" and "your mission understand" actually meant to mean? Were you maybe looking for _understood_ (past tense instead of present tense), as in "your mission understood"? I.e, "we will understand your mission".

Comment: @DarrylNoakes maybe they want ` "your code understand" ` :)  @user19251251 please clarify "other span tags are also getting affected by changing of this text" - effected how? Please edit your question to add clarity.

Answer (score 0):

To target the various `<span>` elements use CSS selectors with `document.querySelector('#my-span')`.

```js
let span = document.querySelector('span');

setTimeout(() => {
  span.textContent = 'bar';
}, 2000 );
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is <span>hello</span> the end.
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, other than a vague hint to have a span per word and only show one of them at a time?

Comment: it introduces the `hidden` HTML parameter and the `querySelector` method for targeting `span` elements. Certainly, updating the `textContent` of an element would be functional here too.

Comment: I still don't see how it actually answers the question of how to do this without the other elements shifting. Your example seems more like a typewriter effect than replacing a word.

Comment: I have updated my example to show how to update the textContent of a particular element.

Comment: I repeat: how does this answer the question of how to do it without affecting the other elements? All this answer gives is the syntax for doing roughly the same as the example in the question with `querySelector()` instead of `getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: I see. PO wants to fix the placement of one element in relation to another.

Comment: "wants to fix the placement of one element in relation to another" your  psychic powers far exceed mine :)

Comment: Well, I assume they wanted the trailing text to be fixed relative to the beginning text. Easiest way to achieve that is CSS `display: inline-block` w a fixed width.

Comment: Why fix span widths to something built in. You cannot know in advance what the widest word’s width will be. It has to be calculated at run time, within the context in which it is going to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For my answer:
I gave each span a display inline block so I can control it as spans are typically inline and you are limited to what you can do with it.

I gave the target span a set with and text-align:center so the text will be aligned within that span.

Then I created a CSS class for reveal that has an animation on it that slides down.

Then I add that class in your showval function. I also used an animation end event listener to remove the class from the span after each animation is completed. So that way it will be restarted everytime I add the class to the span.

Also I switched to using querySelector instead of getElementsByClassName.

I created a function that loops through the content and adds each to a temporary element to determine the widest word. I chose this instead of finding the longest word as different letters have different widths.

```js
var para_values = [
  {
    content: "BRAND "
  },
  {
    content: "MISSION"
  }
];

const getMaxWidth = () => {
  let maxWidth = 0;
  let temp = document.createElement("span");
  temp.classList.add("ib");
  document.body.append(temp)
  para_values.forEach((e) => {
    temp.textContent = e.content;
    if(temp.offsetWidth > maxWidth){
      maxWidth = temp.offsetWidth;
    }
  });
  
  temp.remove()
  return maxWidth;
}
const spanWidth = getMaxWidth();
const wordEle = document.querySelector(".header-para");

wordEle.style.width = spanWidth + "px";

function showVal(index) {
  wordEle.innerHTML = para_values[index].content;
  wordEle.classList.add("reveal")
}

showVal(0);

function textChange() {
  
  var index = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == para_values.length) {
      index = 0;
    }
   
    showVal(index)
  }, 4000)
}

textChange();

wordEle.addEventListener("animationend", (event) => { wordEle.classList.remove("reveal")});
```

```css
.header-para {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 235, 198);
  text-align:center;
}

.ib,
.text-overlay span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 56px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.reveal {
    animation: slide-down 1s;
}

@keyframes slide-down {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    animation: linear;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-overlay">
  <span>Your</span> <span class="header-para"></span><span>Understand</span>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you decide what the width of the gap should be? And animation may or may not be wanted.

Comment: The original question did include a request that the text was also to be animated down from above. I edited that out at the start for focus, as I believe it to be separate to the question. Or is that requirement necessary to know when choosing an implementation?

Comment: @AHaworth I updated my answer to dynamically calculate the width. For the animation, the original pre-edited question did have a request for sliding down.

Comment: To find the widest word you will need to write them into the actual place they are going rather than just  anywhere in the body so that they pick up all the relevant styling.